# Vertical centering of cases in an equation

Tags: equations, amsmath, cases, setspace

Normally, a simple `cases` will get the result below.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    X=\begin{cases}
      0, & \text{if $a=1$} \\
      1, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, in my thesis template, it generates

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.435}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{8pt}
\begin{longtabu}{ll}
    \caption{This is a caption} \\
    Longtable & Longtable \\
    Longtable & Longtable \\
    Longtable & Longtable \\
\end{longtabu}

\begin{equation}
    X=\begin{cases}
      0, & \text{if $a=1$} \\
      1, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I changed the default line spacing by

```latex
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.435}
```

and increased the row spacing by

```latex
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{8pt}
```

My question is how to center the two cases.

Comment: As campa says, as long as you do not provide code that we can test that is suppose to give the image you present, we cannot help.

Comment: Hello, @daleif @campa  I know why this happens. It is because the line `\setlength{\extrarowheight}{8pt}` which was used to increase the vertical spacing for a table, but it also affects the equations as well.

Comment: Again, provide something the rest of us can test. We cannot test any of the sniplets you are posting. Also, if you want you use `\extrarowheight` in a table, then don't change that value globally, place it in side the table float you have around your tabular, then the change it local to that float.

Comment: @daleif The MWE is added. Thanks a lot for you advice.

Comment: If you just need the `\extrarowheight` for that one table, you can reset it to `0pt` afterwards, or else, place the `tabu` in its own scope-limited group to limit the reach of the `\extrarowheight` (assuming that labels are not an issue).

Answer (score 1):

The use of `\setstretch` has adverse effects also on `array`, which `cases` is based on.

I suggest to patch `array` by setting `\arraystretch` to the inverse of the stretch factor.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\setstretch{1.435}
\pretocmd{\array}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.69686}}{}{} % 1/1.435=0.69686

\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{8pt}
\begin{longtabu}{ll}
    \caption{This is a caption} \\
    Longtable & Longtable \\
    Longtable & Longtable \\
    Longtable & Longtable \\
\end{longtabu}
\endgroup

\begin{equation}
    X=\begin{cases}
      0, & \text{if $a=1$} \\
      1, & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

I believe that `\extrarowheight` should always be set locally and not inflicted to all tables.

[image]

Comment: Does `\arraystretch` also affect the row spacing in tables?

Comment: @WZhao Yes, of course.

Comment: I tested your approach, but I cannot see obvious changes of row spacing in tables with different value of `\arraystretch` comparing to spacing in `cases`. I would prefer increasing a little the row spacing rather than the signal spacing in tables.