# Manage spacing of text, equations and tables

Tags: tables, spacing, amsmath, setspace

I use `setspace` to change the spacing in texts.

```latex
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.435}
```

The spacing in equations can be managed by changing `\arraystretch`

@egreg 's approach in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/505283/87806)

```latex
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\array}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.69686}}{}{} % 1/1.435=0.69686
```

or @campa 's approach in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/505224/87806)

```
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{1.435}
\everydisplay=\expandafter{\the\everydisplay\setstretch{1.0}}
```

However, in either way, the row spacing in table is signal spacing and cannot be changed by changing the value in `\arraystretch` or `\setstretch`.

I prefer increasing a little the row spacing in tables rather than the signal spacing. How can I do that?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for this example
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.435}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\pretocmd{\array}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}}{}{} % increase a little for the row spacing in equations

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]

\begin{equation}
    X=\begin{cases}
        \frac{1}{2}, & \text{if $a=1$} \\
        \frac{3}{2} & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Changing the row spacing in the table}
    \begin{tabular}{ c c c }
    \toprule
     cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\
     \midrule
     cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\  
     cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\
     \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Coiuld you please explain what you mean with "signal spacing"? Does `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}` give you the desired result? Apart from that, you might be interested in [Increase LaTeX table row height](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/159257/134144)

Comment: `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}` seems work. I will test more tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

For the spacing of multineline equations, it is possible to play with the `spreadlines` environment from `mathtools`. It doesn't work with the plain `cases` environment but you can use the variant of this environment introduced by `mathtools`.

For tables, you can use `cellspace`, which defines a minimal vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S`  (or `C` if you load `siunitx`). Last, I recommend loading the `caption` package, which enables you to set the skip between caption and float.

Here is an exaggerated example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} % just for this example
\usepackage{mathtools, empheq, nccmath}
\usepackage{booktabs, caption}
\captionsetup{skip=20pt}
\usepackage[math]{cellspace}
\renewcommand{\cellspacetoplimit}{10pt}
\renewcommand{\cellspacebottomlimit}{10pt}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{equation}{\begin{spreadlines}{20pt}}%{\spreadlines{20pt}}%
\AfterEndEnvironment{equation}{\end{spreadlines}}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{empheq}{\begin{spreadlines}{20pt}}%{\spreadlines{20pt}}%
\AfterEndEnvironment{empheq}{\end{spreadlines}}

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.435}
\pretocmd{\array}{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}}{}{} % increase a little for the row spacing in equations

\begin{document}

\lipsum*[1]
\begin{equation}
    X=\begin{cases*}
        \mfrac{1}{2}, & \text{if $a=1$} \\
        \mfrac{3}{2} & \text{otherwise}
    \end{cases*}
\end{equation}

 \begin{empheq}[left ={ X = \empheqlbrace}]{alignat*=2}
     & \mfrac{1}{2}, &\quad & \text{if $a=1$} \\
      & \mfrac{3}{2} & & \text{otherwise}
\end{empheq}

\begin{table}[htbp]
    \centering
    \caption{Changing the row spacing in the table}
    \begin{tabular}{ Sc c c }
    \toprule
     cell1 & cell2 & cell3 \\
     \midrule
     cell4 & cell5 & cell6 \\
     cell7 & cell8 & cell9 \\
     \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]